# Why does my AVPlayerViewController not show playback controls?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

My AVPlayerViewController does not show the video controls even though `.showsPlaybackControls` is set to true. This started with iOS 16 and the weird thing is `.showsPlaybackControls = false` will dismiss the controls visible when they're visible through clicking on the video.

```swift
var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: assetComp)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
playerController.player = player
playerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
self.addChild(playerController)
player.play()
```